# How to use Firebase ChildEventListerner in the query for realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I am doing a project which require the application to get the real time data from the Realtime database. I have use the datasnapshot method to get the data from database in Tracking activity and send all the data to the Map activity to display the data through intent method. The program should go and get the tracking ID in the reference when user insert the tracking ID.

Here is my database data.
[image]

I have try to use addValueEventListerner and the program successful to get the data from the reference when user insert the tracking ID. However, when there is data changes in the database, the program will refresh the whole map activity in order to display the new data.
Below is the code when using addValueEventListerner.

```js
 query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                  Log.i("checking", "this is value message");

                   enterTracking.setError(null);

                   //String IDfromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child(userTrackingID).getValue(String.class);

                   for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                       latitudefromDatabase = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("HostLocation").child("latitude").getValue());
                       Log.i("testing for latitude", latitudefromDatabase);
                       longitudefromDatabase = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("HostLocation").child("longitude").getValue());
                       Log.i("testing for longitude", longitudefromDatabase);
                       String customerAddress = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("customerAddress").getValue());
                       String customerReplyStatus = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("customerReplyStatus").getValue());
                       String id = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("id").getValue());
                       String latitude = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("latitude").getValue());
                       String longitude = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("longitude").getValue());
                       String status = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("status").getValue());

                       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);

                       intent.putExtra("hostlatitude", latitudefromDatabase);
                       intent.putExtra("hostlongitude", longitudefromDatabase);
                       intent.putExtra("customerAddress",customerAddress);
                       intent.putExtra("customerReplyStatus",customerReplyStatus);
                       intent.putExtra("id",id);
                       intent.putExtra("latitude",latitude);
                       intent.putExtra("longitude",longitude);
                       intent.putExtra("status",status);

                       startActivity(intent);

                   }
               }else {
                    enterTracking.setError("Invalid Tracking ID from database");
                    enterTracking.requestFocus();
                   }
                }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("error", databaseError.getMessage());

            }
        });
```

Now I try to use ChildEventListerner and query method to search and retrieve the data from my database. By using ChildEventListerner, the program should display the data without refreshing the whole map activity.
Below is how I try to apply ChildEventListerner.

```js
 private void isTrackingID() {
        String userTrackingID = enterTracking.getText().toString().trim();

        //Long userTrackingIDNumber = Long.parseLong(userTrackingID);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Tracking ID = " + userTrackingID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("HostID");
        //DatabaseReference trackingRef = rootRef.child("tracking");
        //Query query = trackingRef.orderByChild("id").equalTo(userTrackingID);

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("HostID");

        Query query = reference.orderByChild("Reference/ID").equalTo(userTrackingID);

        query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                    Log.i("checking", "this is value message");

                    enterTracking.setError(null);

                    //String IDfromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child(userTrackingID).getValue(String.class);

                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        latitudefromDatabase = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("HostLocation").child("latitude").getValue());
                        Log.i("testing for latitude", latitudefromDatabase);
                        longitudefromDatabase = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("HostLocation").child("longitude").getValue());
                        Log.i("testing for longitude", longitudefromDatabase);
                        String customerAddress = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("customerAddress").getValue());
                        String customerReplyStatus = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("customerReplyStatus").getValue());
                        String id = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("id").getValue());
                        String latitude = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("latitude").getValue());
                        String longitude = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("longitude").getValue());
                        String status = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("status").getValue());

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);

                        intent.putExtra("hostlatitude", latitudefromDatabase);
                        intent.putExtra("hostlongitude", longitudefromDatabase);
                        intent.putExtra("customerAddress",customerAddress);
                        intent.putExtra("customerReplyStatus",customerReplyStatus);
                        intent.putExtra("id",id);
                        intent.putExtra("latitude",latitude);
                        intent.putExtra("longitude",longitude);
                        intent.putExtra("status",status);

                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

However the program cannot go into the map activity and showing "I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config" in the logcat. Guys, how should I do the correction in order to use the query and the ChildEventListerner?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here my Friend

```html
        Query query = reference.orderByChild("Reference/ID").equalTo(userTrackingID);
```

in this line, you will receive the only id of the user which is the "111ww" in your case So Change this line to

```html
Query query = reference.orderByChild("THE UID OF USER");
```

Now you will receive childs (Account,HostLocation,Reference,TrackingID).

Edit:
you can try

```html
     if (dataSnapshot.exists()&&dataSnapshot.child("ID").getvalue().toString.equals(userTrackingID)) {

                  Log.i("checking", "this is value message");

                   enterTracking.setError(null);

                   //String IDfromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child(userTrackingID).getValue(String.class);

                   for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                       latitudefromDatabase = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("HostLocation").child("latitude").getValue());
                       Log.i("testing for latitude", latitudefromDatabase);
                       longitudefromDatabase = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("HostLocation").child("longitude").getValue());
                       Log.i("testing for longitude", longitudefromDatabase);
                       String customerAddress = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("customerAddress").getValue());
                       String customerReplyStatus = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("customerReplyStatus").getValue());
                       String id = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("id").getValue());
                       String latitude = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("latitude").getValue());
                       String longitude = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("longitude").getValue());
                       String status = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("status").getValue());

                       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);

                       intent.putExtra("hostlatitude", latitudefromDatabase);
                       intent.putExtra("hostlongitude", longitudefromDatabase);
                       intent.putExtra("customerAddress",customerAddress);
                       intent.putExtra("customerReplyStatus",customerReplyStatus);
                       intent.putExtra("id",id);
                       intent.putExtra("latitude",latitude);
                       }
```

Comment: Ya, it is correct as the program can receive only the 111ww data when user insert the tracking ID of 111ww. My objective is to get the tracking data when the user inserted the tracking ID. However, after I try many methods, there is no way to query more than one level deep. Hence, I just give up and continue to get the data for 111ww. And now there is a problem in getting the data from database when I try to use ChildEventListerner and I dont know where I wrong...